# Water leaking from one bathroom

Tags: shower

Water leaking from one bathroom through the other. When the shower or the sink is used in the main bathroom, there is a water leak in both bathrooms. Any ideas or comments are welcome.

Comment: Where is the water accumulating?  How about a little more information on what you see and where.

Comment: Info and pix would help us help you. Is one bathroom above the other?